# A required class was missing while executing maven build

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I've faced this error while executing `mvn clean install` command. I've already tried solution which is removing the relevant plugins located under the path '*file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/*' but it didn't solve the issue.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (test) on project tr.com.aselsan.c2.cbs: Execution test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/booter/KeyValueSource

[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2

[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy

[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.22.2/maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.2.jar

[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.22.2/maven-surefire-common-2.22.2.jar

[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar

[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1

[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>tr.com.aselsan:parent:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]

[ERROR] : org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.KeyValueSource
```

here is the build goals in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**note**: problem occured only in my local machine, the jenkins triggered build is successful.

Comment: You can remove the whole build section because this is all default setting. Then try again

Comment: when skipped the test build section, it worked and buid was successful. btw i face this problem all maven based projects, so i need to solve completely

Comment: Try removing the path `file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/` too.

Comment: You don't have to skip you have to delete everything what you posted in your question

Comment: I realized that after removing the path `file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/`, the org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.KeyValueSource was not generated. I added manuelly and works like charm.